# grails generated unit tests failing right after generation

Tags: unit-testing, grails

Currently using grails 2.3.7

Does generated unit tests of grails normally fails after generating?(generate-all)

I noticed that after I scaffolded, some of the generated controller unit tests are failing. Is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. It is expected that a valid field is present in the domain class under test. For example, a domain class `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
    String name
}
```

also it is expected that dev is implementing the `TODO` part in the generated spec. In case of the generated `FooControllerSpec`, this is where the changes needs to be done, populating valid properties for aforementioned `Foo` domain:

```
def populateValidParams(params) {
    assert params != null
    // TODO: Populate valid properties like...
    params["name"] = 'someValidName'
}
```

Comment: I'm usnig Grails 2.4.4 and even setting the params, some tests fails:

    response.redirectedUrl == '/folder/show/1' (says that redirectUrl is null)